# how can calculate $E(X^Y|X+Y=1)$

Tags: expected-value

let $X,Y$ are two independent random variables Bernoulli with probability $P$. how can calculate $E(X^Y|X+Y=1)$

Comment: Hint: There are _four_ outcomes of the experiment. _Two_ of the 4 outcomes result in $X+Y=1$.  Can you identify what the values of $(X,Y)$ are? Let these be $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$.  Then, conditioned on $X+Y=1$, $X^Y$ takes on values $x_0^{y_0}$ and $x_1^{y_1}$.  Can you figure out these values? Can you figure out the probabilities? Can you put it all together?

Comment: hadisanji: is this [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)?

Comment: Follow Dilip tips (+1) and take the opportunity to also compute $\mathrm{E}[X^Y\mid X+Y=0]$ and $\mathrm{E}[X^Y\mid X+Y=2]$. After that, find out what is the random variable $\mathrm{E}[X^Y\mid X+Y]$. It's a function of $X+Y$.

Comment: The simplest and most straightforward solution I can conceive of observes that $\mathbb{E}(X^Y|X+Y=1) = \mathbb{E}(Y^X|X+Y=1)$ due to the exchangeability of $X$ and $Y$.  Averaging these two equal values and exploiting the linearity of expectations shows that the answer can be expressed as $\mathbb{E}(X^Y+Y^X|X+Y=1)/2.$  Since, for all possible values of $X^Y$ for which $X+Y=1$ and $\{X,Y\}\subset\{0,1\}$ it is the case that $X^Y+Y^X=1,$ the answer must be $1/2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's calculate all outcomes for the $X^Y$:

1. $X=0$, $Y=0$ $\Rightarrow X^Y= 0^0 = 1$, $P=(1-p)^2$
2. $X=0$, $Y=1$ $\Rightarrow X^Y= 0^1 = 0$, $P=p(1-p)$
3. $X=1$, $Y=0$ $\Rightarrow X^Y= 1^0 = 1$, $P=p(1-p)$
4. $X=1$, $Y=1$ $\Rightarrow X^Y= 1^1 = 1$, $P=p^2$

Condition $X+Y=1$ means we consider only the two
*equally likely* outcomes 2 and 3, that is, *conditioned*
on $X+Y = 1$, $X^Y$ is a *Bernoulli* random variable with
parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ and so $E[X^Y\mid X+Y = 1] = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: given that $X^Y = 1$ for all events in the conditional sample space constrained by $X+Y=1$, $E[X^Y|X+Y=1] = 1$. Alternatively: $(1+1)/2 = 1$

Comment: @DavidMarx  Could you explain why $X^Y = 1$ whenever $X+Y = 1$? What about the case $X=0, Y=1$?

Comment: My bad, you're right Dilip, I forgot that case: $E[X^Y|X+Y=1]= \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @David Marx: I believe you're wrong: $\mathrm{E}[X^Y\mid X+Y=1]=1/2$.

Comment: Your first outcome is wrong: $0^0=1$

Comment: @M.Berk Isn't how we choose to define $0^0$ irrelevant for this question?

Comment: @DavidMarx Even your revised answer is incorrect, as Zen points out. In fact, user31158 has had the right answer, regardless of how $0^0$ is defined since $(0,0)$ is given as _not_ having occurred because the conditioning event is $X+Y=1$.

Comment: you're right, I was being an idiot and just not being careful. I must have been drunk or something when I commented, it's clearly $1/2$. My mistake.

Comment: @guy yes, absolutely. However, there's no reason to leave misinformation in the question unnecessarily, or to fail to educate the poster (And yes, the definition of $0^0$ is actually up for debate but it's definitely not $0$)

Comment: I have downvoted this question for two reasons: first, the value of $0^0$ is irrelevant--as @Dilip pointed out--and so performing that calculation is beside the point and just confuses the issue; and second, its value cannot be "N/A": the question is nonsensical unless the function $X^Y$ is an (extended) measurable real-valued function, which means an actual definite number has to be assigned to it for all possible arguments.  There really is no debate (in a discrete context like this one where nobody is worried about limiting values) that $0^0=1.$

Comment: @whuber I respectfully request that you reconsider your downvote of user31158's answer because the second of your two reasons -- the change from "$0^0 = 0$" to "N/A" clearly seems to be in response to the discussions following the answer. user31158 joined up only four months ago and naturally has accumulated very few reputation points. His/her original answer was correct in almost all details except irrelevant matters, and to discourage him/her from further participation with a down-vote seems harsh. Why not edit the answer instead to change the offending "N/A" to $1$ and remove the down-vote?

Comment: @Dilip Downvotes, as employed here, are a way to encourage people to improve their own answers.  Whenever I can I check back to see if changes have been made and am glad to remove downvotes and--in most cases--apply a subsequent upvote. I view that as being less heavy-handed than making substantial edits myself.  I was a little more picky than usual in this case because it concerns a straightforward homework question which, when answered in full as was done here, ought (IMHO) to be done so with exemplary clarity and accuracy.